# show that if $g \cdot b \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then $b$ is also a primitive root of $U_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $g$ is a primitive root of $U_n$ and $g \cdot b \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then $b$ is also a primitive root of $U_n$.

---

What property of primitive root should I use?

How about $g \in U_n$ is a primitive root if $g^{\frac{\phi(n)}{p}} \not\equiv{1} \pmod n$??

because $n$ isnt necessary a prime.. thats not much I can do..

Any hints??

Comment: The property you suggest using should work. What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: $g^{\frac{\phi(n)}{p}} \cdot b \not\equiv{1\cdot {b}} \pmod n$, doesnt really mean anything...

Comment: You are trying to show $b$ is a primitive root. You have a condition for something to be a primitive root. Apply that condition to $b$, and then use what you know about $g$.

Comment: I don't know what $U_n$ is, nor what a primitive root of $U_n$ could be. I presume what is meant is a [primitive root modulo $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n), or more precisely a generator for the multiplicative group of the ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ (presuming the latter is cyclic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that

$$
\left(g \cdot b\right)^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} \equiv 1 \mod n
$$
And
$$
g^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} \not\equiv 1 \mod n
$$
Let $g^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} = K\not\equiv 1$. Now,

$$
K \cdot b^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} \equiv 1 \mod n
$$
But $K^p \equiv 1$, so

$$
b^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} \equiv K^{p-1} = Q \mod n
$$
Now $K Q \equiv 1$. If $Q\equiv 1$, then $KQ\equiv K$, which is a contradiction, as $K \not\equiv 1$. So $Q\not\equiv 1$. Therefore

$$
b^\frac{\phi(n)}{p} \not\equiv 1 \mod n
$$
And b is a primitive root of $U_n$.

Answer (score 1):

we know that $g$ is a primitive root iff its order is equal to $\Phi(n)$

Comment: so we show $b=\phi(n)$ too, but what about it

Comment: order of $g$ is the least natural number $d$ s.t. $g^d=1$ (mod  $n$)